# Logstash + Elasticsearch failover locally or retry

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash

I have a working Redis backed ELK stack, however occasionally, I will have a problem when ElasticSearch is not available for one reason or other.

Flow of log events:

1. Servers generate logs
2. Servers run log-courier, collecting logs, pushing remotely to a Logstash server
3. Logstash-incoming writes to a local Redis service
4. Redis holds events to be processed, acting as a buffer
5. Logstash-outgoing reads from the Redis queue, runs grok and other filters, then outputs to the Elasticsearch cluster.

logstash-incoming.conf

```
input {
  courier {
    port => 123
    transport => "tcp"
  }
}
output {
  redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    data_type => "list" 
    key => "logstash"
  }
}
```

logstash-outgoing.conf

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    data_type => "list" 
    key => "logstash"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearchcluster.local"
  } 
}
```

If there is a failure at step 5, the events are popped from Redis, Logstash will try three times, then blackhole the bulk payload, causing holes in my data collection.

Is there a way to either:

1. Extend out the retry from 3 times x 2 seconds of wait to something much more generous.
2. Write failed payloads to disk, allowing me to pipe them back into ElasticSearch when the problem has resolved.
3. Ideally, both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at the moment of writing neither of the two is possible. Regarding point 2. A dead letter queue facility has been on the roadmap but apparently didn't make to a release yet. Check out these two tickets:

- https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2533
- https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2607

Bye,
Markus